# Subquery (Erro SQL (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row)

Tags: mysql, sql

Criei a seguinte **query**:

```sql
SELECT
    a.`CPF/CNPJ`,
    a.Cliente,
    a.Cep,
    a.Cidade,
    a.Estado,
    COUNT(a.`CPF/CNPJ`) AS Novas_Instancias,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(c.`CPF/CNPJ`)
      FROM relat_instancias c 
      GROUP BY c.`CPF/CNPJ`
    ) AS Total_Instancias
FROM relat_instancias a
LEFT JOIN relat_form_pag_cartao b
    ON a.Pedido = b.Pedido
WHERE a.Data_abertura > '2019-03-01'
    AND b.lista_casamento = 'Nao'
    AND a.Analisado IS NULL
GROUP BY a.`CPF/CNPJ`
ORDER BY Novas_Instancias DESC
```

Que me **retorna**:

> Erro SQL (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

A ideia inicial era consultar quantos novos logs de CPF/CNPJ eu tenho e essa informação vir em uma coluna e em outra coluna o total com os logs antigos e os novos.

**Exemplo:**

CPF XXXXXXXXXXX de Janeiro até Agosto tinha 10 logs, porém agora é Setembro e tenho um 1 novo que foi inserido na tabela.

O retorno esperado é o **seguinte**:

CPF,
Data,
Cep,
Cidade,
Estado,
Novo log,
Total log

Existe alguma possibilidade de corrigir isso?

Comment: a sub consulta (`SELECT COUNT(c.'CPF/CNPJ') FROM relat_instancias c GROUP BY c.'CPF/CNPJ'`) vai agrupar por cpf, então pode trazer mais de um retorno.. teria que adicionar um `where` ou `top 1` ou algo do tipo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução alternativa seria colocar um `WHERE` no lugar do `GROUP BY` do subselect.

```
SELECT
    a.`CPF/CNPJ`,
    a.Cliente,
    a.Cep,
    a.Cidade,
    a.Estado,
    COUNT(a.`CPF/CNPJ`) AS Novas_Instancias,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM relat_instancias c 
        WHERE c.`CPF/CNPJ` = a.`CPF/CNPJ`
    ) AS Total_Instancias
FROM relat_instancias a
LEFT JOIN relat_form_pag_cartao b
    ON a.Pedido = b.Pedido
WHERE
    a.Data_abertura > '2019-03-01'
    AND b.lista_casamento = 'Nao'
    AND a.Analisado IS NULL
GROUP BY a.`CPF/CNPJ`
ORDER BY Novas_Instancias DESC
```

Quanto à performance disso já é outra história.

Comment: Fala Diego, muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda! Do jeito que enviou funcionou perfeitamente. Para maior entendimento, poderia me explicar um pouco mais o que você fez nesta subquery? Só uma pequena descrição mesmo, não entendi muito bem o (WHERE c.`CPF/CNPJ` = a.`CPF/CNPJ`). Você é o cara!

Comment: Como o amigo @rLinhares falou no comentário lá da sua pergunta, um `GROUP BY` vai retornar vários resultados agrupados por cpf/cnpj, já o `WHERE` dessa forma que sugeri restringe a contagem apenas ao cpf/cnpj corrente da query principal e retorno somente um resultado, deu pra sacar? rs

Answer (score 1):

Não deveria ser algo assim? Estou sem sql para testar, mas acredito ser algo nessa linha...

```
SELECT
    a.`CPF/CNPJ`,
    a.Cliente,
    a.Cep,
    a.Cidade,
    a.Estado,
    SUBQUERY.Total_Instancias 
FROM relat_instancias a
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT COUNT(*) Total_Instancias ,c.`CPF/CNPJ`
      FROM relat_instancias c 
      GROUP BY c.`CPF/CNPJ`
    ) SUBQUERY ON A.CPF/CNPJ = SUBQUERY.CPF/CNPJ
LEFT JOIN relat_form_pag_cartao b
    ON a.Pedido = b.Pedido
WHERE a.Data_abertura > '2019-03-01'
    AND b.lista_casamento = 'Nao'
    AND a.Analisado IS NULL
GROUP BY a.`CPF/CNPJ`
ORDER BY Novas_Instancias DESC
```